# Can't connect to jboss server - Operation failed with status WAITING

Tags: java, ejb, jboss7.x, windows-firewall

Got this exception while trying to connect to local jboss server (wildfly-8.2.0.Final)

```
    javax.naming.NamingException: Failed to create remoting connection [Root exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Operation failed with status WAITING]
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.ClientUtil.namingException(ClientUtil.java:36)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory.getInitialContext(InitialContextFactory.java:121)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:684)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:313)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:244)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:216)
    at com.sample.CalculatorIntegrationTestCase.obtainProxyReferences(CalculatorIntegrationTestCase.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:67)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Operation failed with status WAITING
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.IoFutureHelper.get(IoFutureHelper.java:89)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.NamingStoreCache.getRemoteNamingStore(NamingStoreCache.java:56)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory.getOrCreateCachedNamingStore(InitialContextFactory.java:166)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory.getOrCreateNamingStore(InitialContextFactory.java:139)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory.getInitialContext(InitialContextFactory.java:104)
    ... 18 more
```

JNDI properties are following:

```
@BeforeClass
    public static void obtainProxyReferences() throws Throwable {

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
        properties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "remote://localhost:4447");
        properties.put("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context", true);
        properties.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
        properties.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "testuser");
        properties.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "!Test1");
        namingContext = new InitialContext(properties);

        bean = (MeBeanImpl) namingContext.lookup(JNDI_NAME);
    }
```

Telnet also says that it can't connect to server with the port 4447. I opened this port in the firewall but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

By default WildFly uses `8080` as the remoting port. The EJB client API uses the http port, with the http-upgrade functionality, for communicating with the server for remote invocation.

Eg:

```
Properties jndiProps = new Properties();
jndiProps.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
jndiProps.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"http-remoting://localhost:8080");
jndiProps.put("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context", true);
jndiProps.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "testuser");
jndiProps.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "!Test1");

// create a context passing these properties
Context ctx = new InitialContext(jndiProps);
// lookup
ctx.lookup(JNDI_NAME);
```

See: [Remote EJB invocations via JNDI - EJB client API or remote-naming project](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Remote+EJB+invocations+via+JNDI+-+EJB+client+API+or+remote-naming+project)

Comment: javax.naming.NamingException: Failed to connect to any server. Servers tried: [http-remoting://localhost:8080]

Answer (score 0):

instead of using "remote://localhost:4447" use "http-remoting://localhost:8080"

```
properties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "http-remoting://localhost:8080");
```

When you configure jndi properties in code, lookup name should not contain `ejb:`

```
JNDI_NAME = "ear-name/ejb-name/beanClass!beanInterface.fullpath");
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're using maven, don't forget to add this dependency:

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
    <artifactId>wildfly-ejb-client-bom</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.0.Final</version>
    <type>pom</type>
  </dependency>
```

For JMS, you'll need these as well:

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hornetq</groupId>
    <artifactId>hornetq-jms-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.13.Final</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hornetq</groupId>
    <artifactId>hornetq-core-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.13.Final</version>
  </dependency>
```

This should be the only dependency you need.